# Android. Creating socket connection between few devices

Tags: java, android, sockets, kotlin, wifi

For my project I need to connect few devices.
Main idea: one device becomes a 'Server', another ones - 'Clients'. 'Server' contains all business logic, gets data from 'Clients' and receives it to them.

And I've faced huge problem with creating connection between devices:

1. I tried `com.google.android.gms.nearby` package.
   It works well, but to slow. Can be used with 2-4 devices, but with 6-7 there is problem with initial connect, so this way is not suitable.
2. I tried `MulticastSocket` from `java.net` package
   And faced problems with even 3 devices - sometime device just not receive a package and this problem is not stable and unpredictable. So i couldn't fix it.
3. The next was `org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket` package:

```
class CustomWebSocketServer(private val listener: (socket: WebSocket, message: String) -> Unit) :
    WebSocketServer(InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(ADDRESS), PORT)) {

    companion object {
        const val ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"
        const val PORT = 8887
    }

    override fun onOpen(conn: WebSocket?, handshake: ClientHandshake?) {}

    override fun onClose(conn: WebSocket?, code: Int, reason: String?, remote: Boolean) {}

    override fun onMessage(conn: WebSocket?, message: String?) {
        conn ?: return
        listener(conn, message ?: "")
    }

    override fun onMessage(conn: WebSocket?, message: ByteBuffer?) {
        message ?: return
        val buffer = ByteArray(message.remaining())
        message.get(buffer)
        onMessage(conn, String(buffer, Charsets.UTF_16))
    }

    override fun onStart() {}

    override fun onError(conn: WebSocket?, ex: Exception?) {}
}

class CustomWebSocketClient(private val listener: (String?) -> Unit) :
    WebSocketClient(URI("ws://$ADDRESS:$PORT")) {
    override fun onOpen(handshakedata: ServerHandshake?) {}

    override fun onClose(code: Int, reason: String?, remote: Boolean) {}

    override fun onMessage(message: String?) {
        listener(message)
    }

    override fun onMessage(bytes: ByteBuffer?) {
        bytes ?: return
        val buffer = ByteArray(bytes.remaining())
        bytes.get(buffer)
        onMessage(String(buffer, Charsets.UTF_16))
    }

    override fun onError(ex: Exception?) {}
}
```

and using in code:

```
// server
private val serverSocket = CustomWebSocketServer { _, _ -> }

serverSocket.isReuseAddr = true
serverSocket.start()

//client
private val socket: CustomWebSocketClient = CustomWebSocketClient(ADDRESS, PORT) {}

socket.connectBlocking()
socket.sendPing()
```

And it leads to crash on `socket.sendPing()` line. Actually `onError` method of `CustomWebSocketClient` gets exception:

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 8887) from /:: (port 37523): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

4. Finally I've tried standart `Socket` from `java.net` package
   I created `ServerSocket` registered it with `NsdManager` and connected `Socket` - all this gone well. And here is a problem - some devices just don't receive packages at all.

So, does anybody can give some advice - how can I fix one of the problems above or maybe try something else to connect devices?

Comment: `ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 ` Why are you using 127.0.0.1.? That is the loopback address. A client using this address assumes that the server runs on the same device as the client runs. Is that what you are experimenting with?

Comment: Further you did not tell where all those devices reside. Are they all connected to the same local network by wifi?

Comment: I tried different addresses ("228.5.6.7" for example) - result the same. For now I test it - all devices are lay on my table nearby and connect to one network

Comment: Why would you try 228.5.6.7 ? A client should use the ip address of the server. Are you doing that?

Comment: Address is the constant for both - server and client

Comment: `A client should use the ip address of the server. Are you doing that?` And a server app does not need to use an ip-address. Only the client. How are you determining the ip-address of the device where your server is running on?

Comment: I didn't use ip address for `ServerSocket` from `java.net` package. I used it only for `WebSocketServer` from `org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket` package